# Regressing a variable $X_{it}$ on its own total $\sum_i X_{it}$

Tags: regression, least-squares

A variable $X_t$ is divided into components $X_{it}$ such that $\sum_i X_{it} = X_t$ for all $t$.

Consider regressing each component $X_{it}$ separately on the total $X_t$ to get parameter estimates for the constant $b_{i0}$ and slope $b_{i1}$. Then, we have that $\sum_i b_{i0} =0 $ and $\sum_i b_{i1}=1 $.

I don't understand how to show this. And then I will try to calculate this with my dataset.

Comment: Where is the statement come from?

Comment: Just an example in lecture notes

Comment: @Zhanxiong, would you mind taking a look at my answer? The question seems valid to me. In your extreme case, if all components of $X_t$ are identical over $t$, we would have multicollinearity with the constant, so indeed no unique OLSE. In case where there is no variation over $i$, you would explain each $X_{it}$ by a multiple of $k$ times itself, itself, so still the best estimate would be $(0,1/k)'$ and the sum would equal $(0,1)'$ (with $k$ the number of elements in the sum over $i$).

Comment: @ChristophHanck Your answer is right.  I must have reversed the role of response and predictors.

Answer (score 6):

We have a regression of $y_i=(X_{it})_{t=1,\ldots,T}$ on
$$
X=\left(1\;\;\sum_iX_{it}\right)_{t=1,\ldots,T}=(1\;\;X_{t})_{t=1,\ldots,T}
$$ so that
$$
X'X=\begin{pmatrix}T&\sum_tX_t\\\sum_tX_t&\sum_tX_t^2\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
X'y_i=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_tX_{it}\\\sum_tX_tX_{it}\end{pmatrix}
$$
Hence, (notice the terms in the inverse do not depend on $i$)
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_ib_i&=&\sum_i\begin{pmatrix}b_{0i}\\ b_{1i}\end{pmatrix}\\&=&(X'X)^{-1}\sum_iX'y_i
\\
&=&(X'X)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}\sum_t\sum_iX_{it}\\\sum_tX_t\sum_iX_{it}\end{pmatrix}\\
&=&(X'X)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}\sum_tX_t\\\sum_tX_t^2\end{pmatrix}\\
&=&\frac{1}{T\sum_tX_t^2-(\sum_tX_t)^2}\begin{pmatrix}\sum_tX_t^2&-\sum_tX_t\\-\sum_tX_t&T\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\sum_tX_t\\\sum_tX_t^2\end{pmatrix}\\
&=&\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Numerical illustration:

```
n <- 100
k <- 5
X <- matrix(rnorm(n*k), ncol=k)
Xs <- rowSums(X)
coefs <- sapply(1:k, function(i) summary(lm(X[,i]~Xs))$coef[,1])

> rowSums(coefs)
 (Intercept)           Xs 
2.515349e-16 1.000000e+00
```